# VScode Intellisense when using data property in the route Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, router

I have a small question, when I use the data property in the route (to pass isEditMode):

```
const adminChildrenRoute: Routes = [
  { path: 'donuts', component: DonutListComponent },
  {
    path: 'donuts/new',
    component: DonutSingleComponent,
    data: { isEditMode: false },
  },
  {
    path: 'donuts/:id',
    component: DonutSingleComponent,
    data: { isEditMode: true },
  },
];
```

In the component to get the , I use this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.isEditMode =       this.activatedRout.snapshot.data.isEditMode;
 
  }
```

But VScode doesn't give me intellisence to choose the isEditMode, ma question there is any way to have this intellisence? thank you

Comment: With `Ctrl` + `Space` doesn‘t work? And on other code snipped, you become  suggestion from IntelliSense?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen it's work for other code, but for after <data> I don't have suggestions.